# I have these modules on Azure why am I getting Recipe phantom-pdf was not found.?

Tags: node.js, pdf, azure, phantomjs, jsreport

I have phantom-pdf 0.2.2, phantomjs 1.9.15 and jsreports 0.2.3 installed with npm on Azure.   I let azure install with package.json on deployment but I get the error Recipe phantom-pdf was not found. when I go to this route:

```
app.route('/pdfreport')
    .get(function (req, res) {

        require('jsreport').render({
            template: {
                content: "blank",
                phantom: {
                    url: "http://google.com",
                    orientation: "portrait",
                    width: "300px"
                }
            }
        }).then(function(out) {
            out.result.pipe(res);
        }).fail(function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    });
```

What in the world am I doing wrong?  It works on both my local Mac and my local Windows machine

Comment: This looks an awful lot like your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427684/i-get-error-phantom-pdf-recipe-was-not-found-and-then-another-error-when-using-j). What's the difference?

Comment: The difference is I have it working now on more than one local machine but it is not working on Azure... I got it working following the answer from my previous question.  This seems to be related to Azure

Comment: Can you be more specific about your Azure deployment? Is it an azure VM, Cloud Service, WebSite ? Is it a windows or linux machine?

Comment: It is a WebSite created under the compute menu... it is running windows

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid phantom-pdf recipe won't run on Azure Websites because this shared hosting environment is blocking GDI+ api required for rendering pdf.

You have to create a full VM to run jsreport in azure.

Comment: Would it be better to use the jsreports online api solution?  I have an account already.  What would I have to do modify in my route to target the api and return a pdf in the browser similar to how my current route does?

Comment: This is rather a political decision. jsreprot SaaS removes the burden of maintenance where local jsreport gives you full control over updates for example. Technically both ways should work for you. Actually there are already several companies using Azure Websites together with jsreportonline SaaS.